# Internal keyboard of Medion Akoya S15449 not recognized

Tags: boot, drivers, keyboard

I recently bought a Medion Akoya S15449 Laptop (MD 63785).
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is on a bootable USB-stick created with Rufus.
The system boots and I can get into the "try" and "install" part of the distribution.
An external USB-keyboard is recognized, the internal one isn't.

First of all I am not an expert regarding hardware and drivers etc.
So, my first gues on this behaviour is a unknown/buggy/inkonsistent driver for this keyboard.

Has somebody an idea, what to do know, or even better: a solution?

Here is what lshw -C input says:
*-usb
Beschreibung: Tastatur
Produkt: HP Basic USB Keyboard
Hersteller: CHICONY
Physische ID: 1
Bus-Informationen: usb@3:3.1
Version: 3.00
Fähigkeiten: usb-1.10
Konfiguration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=1Mbit/s
*-pnp00:03
Produkt: PnP device PNP0303
Physische ID: 4
Fähigkeiten: pnp
Konfiguration: driver=i8042 kbd

and this is the output of lsusb:
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0bda:0316 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB3.0-CRW
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 1f75:0903 Innostor Technology Corporation Intenso Ultra Line
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 13d3:56f5 IMC Networks USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 03f0:0024 HP, Inc KU-0316 Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp.
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

The HP-keyboard is the external USB-keyboard I used to get this information.

Comment: Hmm … [this may be a known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1909814). I’ve done some digging, but there does not seem to be any simple solution. Can you update your question to include the output of `sudo lshw -C input` and `lsusb`? This will include some hardware-specific information that might reveal why your keyboard is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the link above, please refer to
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213031

At the bottom you find a final patch release for the Linux kernel. With some luck it'll land in kernel 5.14.